# Visual DataGridBoolColumn bug in Datagrid when RowHeadersVisible = false

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid(not DataGridView) and I want to hide the RowHeader. The problem is after I set the property RowHeaderVisible to false, a visual bug appears with DataGridBoolColumn. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiVEb.jpg) is the normal state and then once you moved the Checkbox out of the screen to the left and back in it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGWRw.jpg).Putting the RowHeaderWidth to 0 only makes the RowHeader smaler but not invisible. How can I not have a RowHeader and not have this visual bug?

Here is the code i used to fill the DataGrid:

VB:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    MyBase.Load
    DataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(New DataGridTableStyle)
    Dim abc As New DataTable
    abc.Columns.Add("a")
    abc.Columns.Add("b")
    abc.Columns.Add("c")
    abc.Columns.Add("Bool", GetType(Boolean))
    abc.Columns.Add("d")
    abc.Columns.Add("e")
    abc.Columns.Add("f", GetType(Boolean))
    abc.Columns.Add("g")
    abc.Columns.Add("h")
    abc.Columns.Add("i")
    abc.Columns.Add("j")
    abc.Columns.Add("k")
    abc.Columns.Add("l")
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    abc.Rows.Add({"t", "s", "sef", False, "se", "eff", False, "se", "eff", "efs", "se", "eff", "efs"})
    For Each tmpColumn As DataColumn In abc.Columns
        Dim oSpalte As DataGridColumnStyle
        If tmpColumn.DataType = GetType(Boolean) Then
            oSpalte = New DataGridBoolColumn
        Else
            oSpalte = New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        End If
        oSpalte.ReadOnly = True
        oSpalte.Width = 100
        oSpalte.MappingName = tmpColumn.ColumnName
        DataGrid1.TableStyles.Item(0).GridColumnStyles.Add(oSpalte)
        DataGrid1.TableStyles.Item(0).MappingName = "Table"
    Next
    Me.DataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = False
    Me.DataGrid1.PreferredColumnWidth = 200
    Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = abc
End Sub
```

C#

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
DataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(new DataGridTableStyle());
DataTable abc = new DataTable();
abc.Columns.Add("a");
abc.Columns.Add("b");
abc.Columns.Add("c");
abc.Columns.Add("Bool", typeof(bool));
abc.Columns.Add("d");
abc.Columns.Add("e");
abc.Columns.Add("f", typeof(bool));
abc.Columns.Add("g");
abc.Columns.Add("h");
abc.Columns.Add("i");
abc.Columns.Add("j");
abc.Columns.Add("k");
abc.Columns.Add("l");
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
abc.Rows.Add(
{
    "t",
    "s",
    "sef",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    false,
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs",
    "se",
    "eff",
    "efs"
});
foreach (DataColumn tmpColumn in abc.Columns)
{
    DataGridColumnStyle oSpalte;
    if (tmpColumn.DataType == typeof(bool))
        oSpalte = new DataGridBoolColumn();
    else
        oSpalte = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
    oSpalte.ReadOnly = true;
    oSpalte.Width = 100;
    oSpalte.MappingName = tmpColumn.ColumnName;
    DataGrid1.TableStyles.Item(0).GridColumnStyles.Add(oSpalte);
    DataGrid1.TableStyles.Item(0).MappingName = "Table";
}
this.DataGrid1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.DataGrid1.PreferredColumnWidth = 200;
this.DataGrid1.DataSource = abc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there does appear to be some bug in the DataGrid's DataGridBoolColumn drawing code that leaves artifacts on screen during scrolling.

Without digging into the source code to find the proper solution, a simple hack is to subscribe to the DataGrid's scroll event and Invalidate the control to cause it to repaint.

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.Scroll
  DataGrid1.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, it works but all the text in the other columns starts blinking.